# Can I remove commit without making any changes to current code?

Tags: git, github, commit

I have one commit which I would like to remove from history but I want to keep changes. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, but only if you rewrite the history of some other commit(s) to include those changes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. The most common/most straight forward way to do this would be to do an *interactive rebase* and then either do `fixup` or `squash` depending on which way you want to join commits.

As an alternative you could probably create some other branch from some commit back in time and then cherry-pick + amend + rebase, although then you sort of are doing the same as interactive rebase just less formally and possibly more complicated. So interactive rebase should be preferred.

---

For completeness I can inform that commits removed with filter-branch only removes the commits and not their corresponding content. From git-filter-branch(1):

> NOTE the changes introduced by the commits, and which are not reverted by
> subsequent commits, will still be in the rewritten branch. If you want to
> throw out changes together with the commits, you should use the interactive
> mode of git rebase.

so in theory it could be used as well, but that would be a bad idea for several reasons (you would have less precise control on which commits that ends up containing the content from the removed commits, it is easy to screw up with filter-branch, and the man page explicitly tells you it is the wrong tool for the job), so don't.